# Android Broadcastreceiver for other apps install/delete not working

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I have a Broadcastreceiver to detect other apps installs or deletion.

This is my Java

```
public class AppListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context var1, Intent var2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.d("AppTag", "Received!");
}
}
```

This is my manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".AppListener">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
            <data android:scheme="package"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

But whenever I install or delete an app nothing occurs!

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: Android Oreo (8.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to listen to broadcasts like `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` and `ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED`. That is fine for Android 7.1 and lower. On Android 8.0+, you cannot register for those broadcasts in the manifest, as [most implicit broadcasts are banned](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#broadcasts).

Instead, you need to [call `getChangedPackages()` on `PackageManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getChangedPackages(int)) periodically, such as via `WorkManager`. This will not give you real-time results, but real-time results are no longer an option on Android 8.0+.

Comment: Thank you. I want to add that your overall comments on Stackoverflow were more than helpful to me.

Comment: Testing that method on the long run was not reliable at all. For example if I restart my device shortly after an app install, that install will not be detetect by my app :(

Comment: @MoDev: That particular limit does not surprise me. You would have the same limit with the broadcast, in that there is no guarantee that you will receive the broadcast and be able to do meaningful work before the device shuts down. However, the delays introduced by the `WorkManager` polling definitely increase the time when this risk exists.

Comment: And what about battery optimization or Doze mode when dealing with `WorkManager` or `JobScheduler` ?

Comment: @MoDev: I will be surprised if apps are installed or upgraded while those modes are active. And, it is possible that the act of doing the installation/upgrade might allow other jobs to run. Overall, if your app requires 100% reliable real-time knowledge of app installs/upgrades, your app is doomed.

Comment: So what is the logic behind all the available app launchers ? Do they perform real time iterations over installed packages lists ?

Comment: @MoDev: My guess is that they call `queryIntentActivities()` as part of displaying their launcher. There are ways that the launcher contents can vary without apps being installed or updated (e.g., app uninstall, apps using `setComponentEnabledSetting()` to toggle the availability of a launcher activity). But, there are open source launchers out there -- you might look at the code for a few and see what they do.

Comment: Please if you have time would you give a look at my other question ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57576992/android-get-phone-dialer-app-package-instead-of-contacts