# Android get Phone Dialer app package instead of Contacts

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-package-managers

I'm working on an android app where I get list of installed apps using this code:

```
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    List<ResolveInfo> allAppsInstalled = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
```

then I assign each app icon, label and packagename to a recyclerview element where I can launch each package using the appropriate intent

```
Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
                context.startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Every thing is working fine except for the Contacts and Phone apps, both have the same package name 'com.android.contacts' and both open the same app contacts screen. My question is, how can I make the Phone app open the Dialer not the contacts List ?

Comment: are you seeing separate icons for Phone and Contacts in your apps list? if so, launch both launcher icons, and check the logcat for ActivityManager to see how the two intents look like. BTW, this is a device specific issue, device makers usually replace the contacts/phone/call-log apps with something of their own, and each maker implement those apps differently

Comment: Yes I see separate apps, and I already checked their intents and the dialer app directs to 'com.android.contacts.activities.twelvekeydialer' and the main contacts app direct to 'com.android.contacts'. I know that the name of the activity differs according to the manufacturer, but how to handle that ? or how to get app list with the appropriate activity names ?